# UIbutton inside uitableviewcell not responding on scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have uitableview with a custom cell in which I need to show some checkbox and radio button according to type in section. In cellForRowAt my code is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PopupCell") as! PopupCell
                   //   self.mainTbl.beginUpdates()
                    cell.lblHeading.text = self.jsonNew[indexPath.section]["section_attributes_topping"][indexPath.row].stringValue
                    cell.lblPrice.text = "€"+self.jsonNew[indexPath.section]["section_attributes_price_topping"][indexPath.row].stringValue
                    cell.radioButton.tag = self.jsonNew[indexPath.section]["id"][indexPath.row].intValue


                    if self.jsonNew[indexPath.section]["type_attr"].stringValue == "radio"{
                        cell.radioButton.setImage(deselectedRadioImage, for: .normal)
                        cell.initCellItem()
                        cell.delegate = self


                    }else{
                        cell.radioButton.setImage(deselectedCheckboxImage, for: .normal)
                        cell.initCellCheckbox()
                        cell.delegate = self
                        cell.delegate_one = self
                    }

                    //cell.clipsToBounds = true
                  print(indexPath)
                   // self.mainTbl.endUpdates()
                    return cell
                }          // self.mainTbl.endUpdates()
    return cell
}
```

it is working fine if no scroll but when i scroll down and select then wrong button selected.
I am new to ios development i know it is problem of cell reuse but how can i solve it. I did googling but not get any proper answer.

My cell code

```
                //
            //  PopupCell.swift
            //  AppAndEat
            //
            //  Created by Ravi Thakur on 11/08/18.
            //  Copyright © 2018 DevelopersGroup. All rights reserved.
            //

            import UIKit
            struct Product {
                var price = 0
                var name = ""
                var attr = ""
                var heading = ""
            }

            protocol PopupCellDelegate {
                func didToggleRadioButton(_ indexPath: IndexPath)
            }


            class PopupCell: UITableViewCell {

                var product : Product!

                private var counterValue = 1
                var productIndex = 0

                @IBOutlet weak var lblQty: UILabel!
                @IBOutlet weak var btnMinus: UIButton!
                @IBOutlet weak var btnPLusg: UIButton!
                var delegate: PopupCellDelegate?
                var delegate_one: PopupCellGetValue?
                @IBOutlet weak var lblPrice: UILabel!

                @IBOutlet weak var lblHeading: UILabel!
                @IBOutlet weak var radioButton: UIButton!
                override func awakeFromNib() {
                    super.awakeFromNib()
                    // Initialization code
                }

                override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
                    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

                    // Configure the view for the selected state
                }
                func initCellItem() {

                    let deselectedImage = UIImage(named: "circle-shape-outline (1)")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                    let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "dot-and-circle (1)")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                    radioButton.setImage(deselectedImage, for: .normal)
                    radioButton.setImage(selectedImage, for: .selected)

                    radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.radioButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                }
                func initCellCheckbox(){
                    let deselectedCheckBoxImage = UIImage(named: "blank-check-box")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                    let selectedCheckboxImage = UIImage(named: "check")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
                    radioButton.setImage(deselectedCheckBoxImage, for: .normal)
                    radioButton.setImage(selectedCheckboxImage, for: .selected)
                    radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.checkButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                }
                @objc func radioButtonTapped(_ radioButton: UIButton) {

                    let isSelected = !self.radioButton.isSelected
                    self.radioButton.isSelected = isSelected
                    if isSelected {
                        deselectOtherButton()
                    }
                    let tableView = self.superview as! UITableView
                    let tappedCellIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: self)!

                    delegate?.didToggleRadioButton(tappedCellIndexPath)
                   // delegate_one?.getAllValue(product: product, indexPath: tappedCellIndexPath)
                }

                func deselectOtherButton() {
                    let tableView = self.superview as! UITableView
                    let tappedCellIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: self)!
                    let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
                    for indexPath in indexPaths! {
                        if indexPath.row != tappedCellIndexPath.row && indexPath.section == tappedCellIndexPath.section {
                            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: indexPath.section)) as! PopupCell
                            cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
                        }
                    }
                }
                //function for checkboxes
                @objc func checkButtonTapped(_ radioButton: UIButton) {

                    let isSelected = !self.radioButton.isSelected
                    self.radioButton.isSelected = isSelected
                    if isSelected {
                        print(self.radioButton.isSelected)
                        self.radioButton.isSelected = isSelected
                        self.btnMinus.isHidden = false
                        self.btnPLusg.isHidden = false
                        self.lblQty.isHidden = false

                    }else{
                        self.btnMinus.isHidden = true
                        self.btnPLusg.isHidden = true
                        self.lblQty.isHidden = true
                        counterValue = 1
                        self.lblQty.text = "\(counterValue)"


                       // self.radioButton.isSelected = !isSelected
                    }
                    let tableView = self.superview as! UITableView
                    let tappedCellIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: self)!
                    delegate?.didToggleRadioButton(tappedCellIndexPath)

                }

                //function for plus minus qty

                @IBAction func clickMinus(_ sender: Any) {
                    if(counterValue != 1){
                        counterValue -= 1;
                    }
                    self.lblQty.text = "\(counterValue)"

                    let tableView = self.superview as! UITableView
                    let tappedCellIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: self)!
                    //delegate?.didToggleRadioButton(tappedCellIndexPath)
                    delegate?.checkPrice(tappedCellIndexPath, price: "\(counterValue)")
                }

                @IBAction func clickPlus(_ sender: Any) {
                    counterValue += 1;
                    self.lblQty.text = "\(counterValue)"
                }
            }
```

Comment: show your cell.delegate, cell.initCellCheckbox()

Comment: @UnrealDeveloper i have updated code please check

Comment: in which tableview method running first code block (if self.jsonNew[indexPath.section]["type_attr"].stringValue == "radio" etc..)? didSelectRowAt?

Comment: @unreal developer i used first code inside cellForRowAt

Comment: ok, show me how are you detecting your radio button click and checkbox click. Because i cannot understand your problem right now, but i can help if i will understand)

Comment: @UnrealDeveloper I have add entire code for uitableviewcell

Comment: sorry, maybe i didn't understand again) if you scroll down and select radio button for example - then right on is selecting, and if you scroll down even more, then scroll back again - then your right radio button isn't selected - right? if right, i need to edit my answer, sorry :)

Comment: First time i select then it select right button and if i scroll down and tap on button then not working means it select above button . I think cell index mismatch

Comment: ok, try to print your tappedCellIndexPath in Tapped actions and check if it's right. if not, then my answer should help you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

`let tableView = self.superview as! UITableView
 let tappedCellIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: self)!`
doesn't return the right indexPath for you.

Create something like that:

```
protocol PopupCellDelegate: class {
func didTap(_ cell: Cell)
```

}

class PopupCell: UITableViewCell {

```
weak var delegate: PopupCellDelegate?
@IBAction func radioButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.didTap(self)
}
```

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, PopupCellDelegate {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ...
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}

func didTap(_ cell: Cell) {
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    cell.delegate?.didToggleRadioButton(indexPath)
}
```

Rebuild this for your cells and actions, it should work. If not, then i will think more about it)

Comment: func didTap(_ cell: Cell) {
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    cell.delegate?.didToggleRadioButton(indexPath)
}
it occure error no delegete member
Also 

@IBAction func radioButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.didTap(self)
}

can not convert to cell

Comment: @RaviThakur add func didToggleRadioButton(_ indexPath: IndexPath) in PopupCellDelegate
and edit to func didTap(_ cell: PopupCell)

Comment: Ok let me do it

Comment: I did get indexpath by func didTap(_ cell: PopupCell) but now how to change image of button of that specific button on tap, I set tag also but same issue

Comment: your did tap code is 
`let isSelected = !self.radioButton.isSelected
                    self.radioButton.isSelected = isSelected

                    if isSelected {
                        deselectOtherButton()
                    }

                    let index = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)

                    cell.delegate?.didToggleRadioButton(index)`

it's for radio button

Comment: for checkbox button copy code from checkButtonTapped and make a new didtap event (name it somehow different) do exactly the same as in checkButtonTapped, but last lines must be changed as in example for radio button, try yourself

Comment: when i click on radio button it sometimes check the checkbox that is main issue and some of radio button is not selecting sometimes

Comment: Update the answer - show me your didToggleRadioButton code

Comment: And try this ‘tableView.delaysContentTouches = false’ in viewDidLoad() this will increase your response ability, but not will fix the issue i think)

Comment: didToggleRadioButton i just get value of selected element
if jsonNew[indexPath.section]["type_attr"] == "radio"{
            radioButtonIndexPath[indexPath.section] = indexPath
        }else{
            if checkboxIndexPath.contains(indexPath) {
                checkboxIndexPath.remove(at: checkboxIndexPath.index(of: indexPath)!)
            }else{
                checkboxIndexPath.append(indexPath)
            }
       }

Comment: My Main goal is in uitableview some of section contain checkbox and some of radiobutton if i check then should be able to select multiple and if radio button then only one selected on that perticular radio button.

Comment: if on radio button sometimes clicking checkbox - then your if statement is bad in didToggleRadio. try to print something and check if it is right. if not, then fix it, and everything should be ok. (sorry but i cant help you with if statement fixing because i have no access to my pc right now, so its so hard to think that abstract )

Comment: data print is ok only checkbox and radio button image is wrong